# How to fix this carousel control position problem?

Tags: html, carousel, bootstrap-5, webusercontrol

I created a html page to test bootstrap 5 carousel.  It displays multiple items and have prev and next controls outside of slide images.  The controls are using glyphicon-chevron-left and glphicon-chevron-right provided by bootstrap. The CSS is used to specify control positions. I run into problem of unable to position "next" control correctly.  Instead of on the right of the last slides, it is actually displayed on the first slide, not far from Prev control. How should I change the CSS style to fix the problem?

Here is my test program:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Modymix Website Prototype</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    @media (max-width: 767px)
    {
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item >div
        {
            display: none
        }
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item >div:first-child
        {
            display: block
        }
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active, .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next, .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev
    {
        display: flex
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px)
    {
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end.active, .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next
        {
            transform: translateX(25%)
        }
        
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start.active, .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev
        {
            transform: translateX(-25%)
        }
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end, .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start
    {
        transform: translateX(0)
    }

    .carousel-control-next-icon 
    {
        right: -30px;
    }

    .carousel-control-prev-icon
    {
        right: -30px;
    }

    /* Adjusted control positioning and styling */
    .carousel-control-prev,
    .carousel-control-next {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }  
    .carousel-control-prev, .glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left  {
        left: -75px;
    }

    .carousel-control-next, .glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right {
        right: -75px;
    }

    .card 
    {
        border-style: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container text-center my-3"> 
    <h2 class="font-weight-light mb-3">Learning Center Category List</h2> 
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto justify-content-center"> 

        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide" > 
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">             
                <div class="carousel-item active">  
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-img text-center"> 
                                <img src="/images/learning/HealthDieNoBackgroundt0911-2023.jpg" 
                                 width="250" height="96"> 
                            </div> 
                            <!-- <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 1</div>                         -->
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                
                <div class="carousel-item"> 
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-img"> 
                                <img src="/images/learning/carbManagementNoBackground911-2023.jpg"
                                width="250" height="96"> 
                            </div> 
                            <!-- <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 2</div>  -->
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                
                <div class="carousel-item"> 
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-img"> 
                                <img src="/images/learning/knowDiabetesCatalog.png" 
                                   width="250" height="96" > 
                            </div> 
                            <!-- <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 3</div>  -->
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                
                <div class="carousel-item"> 
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-img"> 
                                <img src="/images/learning/ResearchUpdateNobackground0911-2023.jpg" 
                                width="250" height="96" > 
                            </div> 
                            <!-- <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 4</div>  -->
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                
                <div class="carousel-item"> 
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-img"> 
                                <img src="/images/learning/LearningCatalog_new.jpg" 
                                    width="250" height="96"> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="card-img-overlay fw-bold" style="color: white"">Catalog 5</div> 
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                
                <div class="carousel-item"> 
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-img"> 
                                <img src="/images/learning/LearningCatalog_new.jpg" 
                                    width="250" height="96"> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="card-img-overlay fw-bold" style="color: white">Catalog 6</div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
            
            <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" 
                role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left " aria-hidden="true" 
                    style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></span>
            </a> 
            
            <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-next bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" 
                role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " aria-hidden="true" 
                    style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></span>
            </a> 
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <h5 class="mt-3 fw-light">advances one slide at a time</h5>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    // carousel jquery script
    let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')

    items.forEach((el) => {
        const minPerSlide = 4
        let next = el.nextElementSibling
        for (var i=1; i<minPerSlide; i++) {
            if (!next) {
                // wrap carousel by using first child
                next = items[0]
            }
            let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
            el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
            next = next.nextElementSibling
        }
    })
  </script> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your adjusted control positioning styling is not having any effect, since it’s overwritten by the bootstrap styles. The only thing having an effect is `transform: translateY(-50%);` which is not needed if you want to have the chevrons centered vertically. Currently they pull them up to the top of the carousel.

To fix your issue adhoc you can add `left: auto` to `carousel-control carousel-control-next`

Have a look into the CSS part of the Code Snipped added below. I commented out your Adjustments and added a single line at the bottom.

explanation:
`left: 0;` is basically the "stronger" one when applied together with `right: 0;`. So to enable the right you have to neutralise the left with `left: auto;` in this case because the `left: 0;` comes from bootstrap and can't be deleted.

btw:

You have 2 versions of bootstrap included:

1. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
2. https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css

You may sort that out.

```js
 // carousel jquery script
    let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')

    items.forEach((el) => {
        const minPerSlide = 4
        let next = el.nextElementSibling
        for (var i=1; i<minPerSlide; i++) {
            if (!next) {
                // wrap carousel by using first child
                next = items[0]
            }
            let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
            el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
            next = next.nextElementSibling
        }
    })
```

```css
@media (max-width: 767px)
    {
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item >div
        {
            display: none
        }
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item >div:first-child
        {
            display: block
        }
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active, .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next, .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev
    {
        display: flex
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px)
    {
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end.active, .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next
        {
            transform: translateX(25%)
        }
        
        .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start.active, .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev
        {
            transform: translateX(-25%)
        }
    }
    
    .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end, .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start
    {
        transform: translateX(0)
    }

    .carousel-control-next-icon 
    {
        right: -30px;
    }

    .carousel-control-prev-icon
    {
        right: -30px;
    }

    /* Adjusted control positioning and styling */
    
    /* Doesn't have any effect other than the transform
    .carousel-control-prev,
    .carousel-control-next {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }  
    .carousel-control-prev, .glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left  {
        left: -75px;
    }

    .carousel-control-next, .glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right {
        right: -75px;
    }
    */
    
    .card 
    {
        border-style: none;
    }
    
    
    /* Fixes the issue */
  
    .carousel-control.carousel-control-next {
        left: auto;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Modymix Website Prototype</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container text-center my-3"> 
    <h2 class="font-weight-light mb-3">Learning Center Category List</h2> 
    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto justify-content-center"> 

        <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide" > 
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">             
                <div class="carousel-item active">  
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-img text-center"> 
                                <img src="/images/learning/HealthDieNoBackgroundt0911-2023.jpg" 
                                 width="250" height="96"> 
                            </div> 
                            <!-- <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 1</div>                         -->
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                
                <div class="carousel-item"> 
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-img"> 
                                <img src="/images/learning/carbManagementNoBackground911-2023.jpg"
                                width="250" height="96"> 
                            </div> 
                            <!-- <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 2</div>  -->
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                
                <div class="carousel-item"> 
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-img"> 
                                <img src="/images/learning/knowDiabetesCatalog.png" 
                                   width="250" height="96" > 
                            </div> 
                            <!-- <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 3</div>  -->
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                
                <div class="carousel-item"> 
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-img"> 
                                <img src="/images/learning/ResearchUpdateNobackground0911-2023.jpg" 
                                width="250" height="96" > 
                            </div> 
                            <!-- <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 4</div>  -->
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                
                <div class="carousel-item"> 
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-img"> 
                                <img src="/images/learning/LearningCatalog_new.jpg" 
                                    width="250" height="96"> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="card-img-overlay fw-bold" style="color: white"">Catalog 5</div> 
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div> 
                
                <div class="carousel-item"> 
                    <div class="col-md-3"> 
                        <div class="card"> 
                            <div class="card-img"> 
                                <img src="/images/learning/LearningCatalog_new.jpg" 
                                    width="250" height="96"> 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="card-img-overlay fw-bold" style="color: white">Catalog 6</div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div> 
                </div> 
            </div> 
            
            <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-prev bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" 
                role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left " aria-hidden="true" 
                    style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></span>
            </a> 
            
            <a class="carousel-control carousel-control-next bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" 
                role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right " aria-hidden="true" 
                    style="color: black; font-size: 25px;"></span>
            </a> 
        </div> 
    </div> 

    <h5 class="mt-3 fw-light">advances one slide at a time</h5>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
   
  </script> 
</html>
```